# Getting "Could not load plugins: File not found" for JWPlayer

Tags: xcode, ipad, video, jwplayer, jwplayer6

We have been working on an iPad app which requires to play Video files without an internet connection. Now the video on iPad App works fine without the internet only when the App is started with the internet connection. Once the App is loaded, then we could turn the internet off and still the videos work.

But when we start the App with internet off, the Player shows the black death screen with `Could not load plugins: File not found` on it.

I guess there is some script being loaded from the internet.

I have a paid "Premium Edition"; does it validate its key before starting?

Comment: How are you embedding the player into an app?